# Laravel 4 Input::all() appending request path to the input array?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

On a fresh install of L4:

**Route.php**

```
Route::post('/test', 'TestController@store');
```

**TestController.php**

```
class TestController extends Controller  {


        /**
         * Store a newly created resource in storage.
         *
         * @return Response
         */
        public function store()

        {

                print_r(Input::get());
                //
        }

}
```

**Curling URL**

```
curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://example.com/test
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [param1] => value1
    [param2] => value2
    [/test] => 
)
```

What is the request URI doing here ??

PS: Using Nginx / Php-fpm stack should that matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turned out to be the ngixn clean URL snippet i was using. Changed it from:

```
 if (!-d $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
    }
```

TO:

```
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

it was working fine before last update though.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is elsewhere in your code, and not Laravel 4.

I just ran the following test using the latest beta build of Laravel 4:

```
Route::post('/test', function()
{
    print_r($_POST);
    print_r(Input::get());
});
```

**view:**

```
<h1>Test</h1>
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="test1" id="test1" value="testfield1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="test2" id="test2" value="testfield2" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**result:**

```
Array ( [test1] => testfield1 [test2] => testfield2 )
Array ( [test1] => testfield1 [test2] => testfield2 )
```

Are you using the input class anywhere else in your code, perhaps in a before filter?

Try the code test above in your code - what result does it give you?

Comment: Thanks for input, i did try on a fresh install and it work fine, now the weird thing is that i striped out all the code form the app to only leave a test controller and i still keep getting this error. I can 't seem to narrow it down to where it's happening..

Comment: did you recently do a composer-update, and forget to update the app core itself?

Comment: Yea everything is up to date

Comment: Including manually updating the app core? If I were you, I'd just move your code into the new blank framework, and see if the error continues. If it does, slowly strip out all your code until it appears.

Comment: Yeah i did update the core, I will give your suggestion a try and see. Thanks again for input.

Comment: Actually jsut tried again on a blank install if you use a URI on your route i have the same problem: Route::post('/test', 'TestController@store');